# Wordpress get_post_meta issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to php and was assigned some code to fix within a Wordpress theme, but I cannot figure it out for anything. The code is for the home page of a custom theme and it is supposed to pull the most recent blog posts and put them in a 3x2 grid at the top of the page.

[Here's](http://test.j2webproduction.com/test/) the page in question

and here's the code from the index.php file (I believe that's where the problem lies)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $woo_options; ?>
<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_featured_disable'] <> "true" ) include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/featured.php'); ?>
<?php

$t = array();

$t[2] = "A";
$t[5] = "B";

query_posts('post_type=infobox&order=ASC&posts_per_page=20&meta_value=false');

if (have_posts()) :

        $a = array(0,1,3,4); $i = 0;

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $m = "";

        $m .= "<div class=\"bskhp_t\" style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px'>";
        $m .= " <a href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\"><img src=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini', $single = true)."\" alt=\"\" class=\"home-icon\"></a>";
        $m .= " <div class=\"bskhp_f\">";
        $m .= "     <h3><a href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\">".get_the_title()."</a></h3>";
        $m .= "     <p>".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_excerpt', true)."</p>";
        $m .= "     <a style='font-family:arial;font-size:13px;text-transform: uppercase' href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\" class=\"btn\">";
        $m .= "     <span>Read More</span></a>";
        $m .= " </div>";
        $m .= "</div>";



        $t[$a[$i++]] = $m;

        endwhile;

endif;

$t[2] = $t[0];
$t[3] = $t[0];
$t[4] = $t[0];
$t[5] = $t[0];

$v = array();

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$v[] = "<div class=\"bskhp_vpv\"><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/who-we-serve/videos/' style='color:#445567;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:500'><img style='padding:4px;border:1px solid #000000; width:180px; height:90px' src='".$upload_dir["baseurl"]."/2015/03/videopreview.jpg' width='180' height='90' vwidth='180' vheight='90' /><div style='color:#000000;font-family:arial;font-size:12px; padding:4px 0'>VIDEO TITLE</div><p style='width:200px'>A local crew in lorem upsum dolor sit amet der despurate...</p></a></div>";
$v[] = $v[0];
$v[] = $v[0];

$p = array();

$p[] = "<div><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/about-us/publications/'><img src='".$upload_dir["baseurl"]."/2015/03/publications_1.jpg' height='254' width='190' /><div class=\"bskhp_pcap\">ANNUAL REPORTS</div></div>";
$p[] = "<div><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/about-us/publications/'><img src='".$upload_dir["baseurl"]."/2015/03/publications_2.jpg' height='254' width='190' /><div class=\"bskhp_pcap\">FACT SHEET &amp; MAPS</div></div>";
$p[] = "<div><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/about-us/publications/'><img src='".$upload_dir["baseurl"]."/2015/03/publications_3.jpg' height='254' width='190' /><div class=\"bskhp_pcap\">NEWSLETTER</div></div>";

$mv = array();

$mv[] = "<h3 class='bskhp_h3'>Our Vision</h3>Housing is just the beginning...the first step to building hope and transforming lives.  We envision a day when every person has a home and a better quality of life.<p class=\"bskhp_rm\"><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/about-us/mission-history/'>READ MORE</a></p>";
$mv[] = "<h3 class='bskhp_h3'>Our Mission</h3>Plymouth Housing Group works to eliminate homelessness and address its causes by preserving, developing and operating safe, quality, supportive housing and by providing homeless adults with opportunities to stabilize and improve their lives.<p class=\"bskhp_rm\"><a href='https://www.plymouthhousing.org/about-us/mission-history/'>READ MORE</a></p>";

?>
<center>
<div id="bskhp_box">

    <!-- tiles -->
    <table style="border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee; width:945px">
        <tr><td colspan="3"><h3 class="bskhp_h3">Latest News <a style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:500' href="javascript:;"><u>Read more from our blog</u></a></h3></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $t[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t[1]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t[2]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $t[3]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t[4]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $t[5]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Two column -->
    <table style="margin:10px 0; padding-bottom:20px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e4e3">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:710px; padding-bottom:15px">
                <table width="100%" id="bskhp_vids">
                    <tr><td colspan="3"><h3 class="bskhp_h3">Videos <a style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px;font-weight:500' href="https://www.plymouthhousing.org/who-we-serve/videos/"><u>View more of our videos</u></a></h3></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%" style="padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e4e3"><?php echo $v[0]; ?></td>
                        <td width="33%" style="padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e4e3"><?php echo $v[1]; ?></td>
                        <td width="34%" style="padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e4e3; border-right:1px solid #e8e4e3"><?php echo $v[2]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding-top:18px; border-right:1px solid #eeeeee"><h3 class="bskhp_h3">Publications</h3></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="33%"><?php echo $p[0]; ?></td>
                        <td width="33%"><?php echo $p[1]; ?></td>
                        <td width="34%" style="border-right:1px solid #e8e4e3"><?php echo $p[2]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width:234px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e4e3">
                <?php get_sidebar('home'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3 class="bskhp_h3" style="width:945px">Funding Partners</h3>
    <div><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir["baseurl"]."/2015/03/financialpartners.jpg"; ?>" /></div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <!-- mission & vision -->
                <table style="width:944px" id="bskhp_mv">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="bskhp_mvl" style="width:50%"><?php echo $mv[0]; ?></td>
                        <td id="bskhp_mvr"><?php echo $mv[1]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code for some reason will not pull the latest blog posts and put them in the 3x2 grid, except for the first two items, and I have no idea why. I believe the problem is within the get_post_meta function, but my knowledge is too sparse to debug it.

Can anyone help? I would be very gracious :)

Comment: I think this belongs to [WordPress Development Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh whoops, i'll move it over there :)